# How do I change the title and description while creating playlist using the YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, playlist

I am trying to change the playlist default name and description by adding the fields in playlist_updates.html, but I am unable to change it.

Here is the reference for the YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#create-a-playlist

Comment: i added the fields for title and description in playlist_updates.html                   and am trying update the code at   // Create a private playlist.
function createPlaylist() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
    part: 'snippet,status',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'Test Playlist',
        description: 'A private playlist created with the YouTube API'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [update API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/update) in order to update playlists.You need to get the playlist ID  of the playlist (which you get from insert's results) and update it like this

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.update({
  part: 'id,snippet',
  resource: {
    id: '{insert playlist id here}',
    snippet: {
      title: 'New Playlist Title',
      description: 'Well this is a new description hope you like it :)'
    }
  }
});
```

Then execute your request

```
request.execute(function(response) {
    var result = response.result;
    if(result){
      alert('updated playlist id : '+  result.id + ' with title: '+ result.snippet.title + ' and description : ' + result.snippet.description);
    } else {
      alert('some error');
    }
});
```